# Select specific column from specific row using old mysql_* API

Tags: php, mysql, select

I've got a table in my SQL Database, and the table has two fields, one for an id, and the other for an integer. I want to grab the value in the integer field where the id is equal to a specific number I pass in. The id field is called "id" and the integer field is called "loglevel". This is the code I've got, but it doesn't give me the desired result.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT loglevel FROM Logs WHERE id='$number'");
echo "Pulled from SQL: " . $result;
```

The output for this is

```
Pulled from SQL: Resource id #2
```

Can you help me so the output is "2" if the value in the SQL table is 2?

Answer (score 4):

You need to fetch your result using [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php), or [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) (or others).  `$result` as returned by `mysql_query()`, is a result resource, not an actual rowset:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT loglevel FROM Logs WHERE id='$number'");

// If the query completed without errors, fetch a result
if ($result) {
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  echo $row['loglevel'];
}
// Otherwise display the error
else echo "An error occurred: " . mysql_error();
```

When you are expecting multiple rows returned rather than just one, fetch them inside a `while` loop. There are many examples of this in the [`mysql_fetch_assoc()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) .

Answer (score 0):

$result = mysql_query("SELECT loglevel FROM Logs WHERE id='$number'");

here $result is a record set/ mysql resource not php array. you need to use  mysql_fetch_assoc(), or mysql_fetch_array() to access $result.

```
if ($result) {
  while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $my_assoc[] = $row;
  }
}
var_dump($my_assoc);
```

this will print all data from the query.