# Get 2 variables in sql and subtract them in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have multiple rows with data, some with data in mysql table `kjoring` and some that don't.
I am able to `echo` both `$km1` and `$km2` correctly, but I am unable to subtract them to find the result and echo $km0

```
$sqlq = "SELECT kjoring FROM oko WHERE kjoring!='' ORDER BY logdate DESC LIMIT 2";

    if ( array_key_exists( 'field' , $out ) ) {
    $sqlq = $sqlq . " where field = '" . $out['field'] . "'" ;
  }
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  $result = mysqli_query( $conn , $sqlq );

  if ( $result->num_rows  > 0 ) {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

  $km1 = $row[0]; 
  $km2 = $row[1];

$km0 = $km1 - $km2 ;  
  }
}

echo $km0 ;
```

Comment: This will help you I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003943/sql-select-specific-column-from-specific-row

Comment: Actually not. I can display the SQL data but I can't get them to stick as variables.

Answer (score 1):

First things first: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says **[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)**. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Next:

```
// $sqlq = 'SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT'
if ( array_key_exists( 'field' , $out ) ) {
    $sqlq = $sqlq . " where field = '" . $out['field'] . "'" ;
}
```

When you add your `WHERE` conditions after the `LIMIT` there WILL be a syntax error returned by your DB. You need to add the `WHERE` condition after the `FROM` and in front of the `ORDER BY`.

```
$sqlq = 'SELECT ... FROM ... ';    
if ( array_key_exists( 'field' , $out ) ) {
    $sqlq = $sqlq . " where field = '" . $out['field'] . "'" ;
}
$sqlq .= 'ORDER BY ... LIMIT ...';
```

Now to the 2 results:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $km1 = $row[0]; 
    $km2 = $row[1];
```

When printing your row using `var_dump()` you will notice that there is only 1  column. You selected just one.

Using `mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);` you will get an array containing both rows. Using this you can then do your computations.

[PHP: mysqli_fetch_all()](https://secure.php.net/mysqli_fetch_all)

Comment: Thank you. But if i get an error by using limit, how can i then limit the results to two?

Comment: I edited the post: You need to have the correct sequence of those parts.

Comment: No. I can't do it. I cant figure out how to do it. Sorry.